# smooth filtering shifts my original signal?

Tags: matlab, filter, filtering, signal-processing, convolution

Here is my code:

```
sigma = 10;
sz = 20;
x = linspace(-sz / 2, sz / 2-1, sz);
    gf = exp(-x .^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
    gf = gf / sum (gf); % normalize

    f_filter = cconv(gf,f,length(f));
```

Basically I am Gaussian filtering original signal `f`. However, when I look at the filtered signal `f_filter`, there is a shift comparing the original signal `f` (See attached figure). I am not sure why this is happening. I would like to only smooth but not shift the orginal signal. Please help. Thanks.
[image]

my original signal `f` is here:

```
-0.0311
-0.0462
-0.0498
-0.0640
-0.0511
-0.0522
-0.0566
-0.0524
-0.0478
-0.0482
-0.0516
-0.0435
-0.0417
-0.0410
-0.0278
-0.0079
-0.0087
-0.0029
0.0105
0.0042
0.0046
0.0107
0.0119
0.0177
0.0077
0.0138
0.0114
0.0103
0.0089
0.0122
0.0122
0.0118
0.0041
0.0047
0.0062
0.0055
0.0033
0.0096
0.0062
-0.0013
0.0029
0.0112
0.0069
0.0160
0.0127
0.0131
0.0039
0.0116
0.0078
0.0018
0.0023
0.0133
0.0140
0.0135
0.0098
0.0100
0.0133
0.0131
0.0086
0.0114
0.0131
0.0175
0.0137
0.0157
0.0040
0.0136
0.0009
0.0049
0.0157
0.0104
0.0038
0.0039
0.0029
0.0126
0.0044
0.0055
0.0040
0.0091
-0.0023
0.0107
0.0151
0.0115
0.0135
0.0160
0.0071
0.0098
0.0094
0.0072
0.0079
0.0055
0.0155
0.0107
0.0108
0.0085
0.0099
0.0055
0.0078
0.0027
0.0121
0.0077
0.0062
0.0021
-0.0019
-0.0003
-0.0022
0.0059
0.0099
0.0114
0.0069
0.0038
0.0020
-0.0031
0.0024
-0.0025
-0.0004
0.0041
0.0059
0.0018
0.0033
0.0130
0.0131
0.0076
0.0084
0.0029
0.0086
0.0078
0.0054
0.0121
0.0101
0.0132
0.0115
0.0074
0.0070
0.0088
0.0017
-0.0003
-0.0060
0.0078
0.0100
0.0044
0.0017
0.0027
0.0062
0.0029
-0.0035
0.0032
0.0060
-0.0035
0.0081
0.0027
0.0043
0.0013
0.0049
0.0119
0.0273
0.0363
0.0435
0.0432
0.0357
0.0424
0.0318
0.0341
0.0354
0.0325
0.0263
0.0320
0.0312
0.0345
0.0407
0.0378
0.0376
0.0334
0.0381
0.0428
0.0375
0.0431
0.0403
0.0395
0.0308
0.0150
0.0006
0.0054
0.0002
0.0090
0.0075
0.0051
0.0067
0.0062
0.0108
0.0059
0.0095
0.0065
0.0087
0.0056
0.0136
0.0057
0.0079
0.0107
0.0106
0.0041
0.0032
0.0106
0.0091
0.0082
0.0025
0.0124
0.0035
0.0034
0.0097
0.0034
0.0050
0.0119
0.0087
0.0081
0.0118
0.0088
0.0050
0.0050
0.0057
0.0118
0.0122
0.0207
0.0112
0.0125
0.0083
0.0125
0.0140
0.0147
0.0237
0.0206
0.0141
0.0164
0.0189
0.0189
0.0136
0.0183
0.0195
0.0209
0.0154
0.0211
0.0254
0.0163
0.0249
0.0236
0.0262
0.0278
0.0285
0.0275
0.0212
0.0277
0.0211
0.0248
0.0289
0.0240
0.0266
0.0479
0.1744
0.4070
0.6818
0.8811
0.9859
0.9347
0.8441
0.7625
0.6396
0.4724
0.3639
0.3406
0.3406
0.3363
0.3318
0.3251
0.3287
0.3135
0.3122
0.3058
0.3103
0.3012
0.2974
0.2995
0.2941
0.2981
0.2968
0.2958
0.2938
0.2929
0.2926
0.2942
0.2982
0.2898
0.2940
0.2927
0.2950
0.2899
0.2979
0.2915
0.2961
0.2921
0.2931
0.2989
0.2941
0.2977
0.3041
0.3042
0.3086
0.3048
0.3069
0.3055
0.3123
0.3138
0.3128
0.3115
0.3092
0.3174
0.3152
0.3106
0.3080
0.3166
0.3109
0.3103
0.3135
0.3101
0.3133
0.3147
0.3044
0.2980
0.2972
0.3013
0.2980
0.3069
0.3932
0.6593
0.8921
1.1071
1.2763
1.3947
1.5076
1.6278
1.7452
1.7993
1.8287
1.8470
1.8957
1.9408
1.9791
2.0272
2.0686
2.0974
2.1335
2.1790
2.2134
2.2545
2.2903
2.3163
2.3585
2.3739
2.4126
2.4503
2.4787
2.5198
2.5447
2.5950
2.6228
2.6410
2.6812
2.7123
2.7557
2.8584
3.2480
3.5315
3.6808
3.7632
3.7471
3.7283
3.6692
3.6718
3.7756
3.9672
4.0376
3.9092
3.7276
3.6586
3.5948
3.6392
3.5671
3.6003
3.6194
3.6350
3.6624
3.6855
3.6958
3.9105
4.3880
5.1342
5.6176
6.3206
7.0392
7.3767
7.5715
7.6516
7.6469
7.5871
7.4591
7.6004
7.5532
7.3601
7.1487
5.9728
4.8974
4.5850
4.4268
4.3352
4.2887
4.3376
4.3182
4.2909
4.2777
4.2548
4.2677
4.2511
4.2817
4.3847
4.4418
4.4696
4.4932
4.4998
4.5151
4.5096
4.5278
4.5139
4.5020
4.4561
4.4067
4.3841
4.3638
4.3750
4.4366
4.5258
4.6565
4.6485
4.5836
4.5183
4.4583
4.3747
4.3509
4.2938
4.2823
4.2844
4.3135
4.3262
4.3255
4.2568
4.2011
4.1832
4.2278
4.2445
4.2409
4.2784
4.2917
4.3035
4.3015
4.3209
4.3204
4.3356
4.3287
4.3260
4.3483
4.3710
4.3798
4.3802
4.3805
4.5162
4.6906
5.0826
5.6588
6.0137
6.2436
6.5361
7.0790
7.6106
7.6410
7.4120
7.4535
7.2476
7.2596
7.1012
7.0986
6.9395
6.5633
5.8438
4.9434
4.6750
4.4320
4.3063
4.2096
4.0193
3.9698
4.0055
4.0218
4.0426
4.0688
4.0650
3.9793
3.9787
3.9766
3.9981
4.0405
4.0165
4.0290
4.0923
4.0897
4.0615
4.0258
4.0008
4.0274
4.0553
4.0646
4.0442
4.0477
3.9986
4.0354
4.0718
4.0563
4.0189
3.8631
3.8144
3.7736
3.8055
3.9730
4.0299
4.0148
3.8265
3.4675
3.3020
3.2474
3.2338
3.1986
3.1680
3.1289
3.0944
3.0523
3.0094
2.9510
2.9246
2.9057
2.8805
2.8545
2.8245
2.7690
2.7236
2.6833
2.6443
2.5969
2.5415
2.4684
2.4214
2.3699
2.3293
2.2513
2.1963
2.1285
2.0700
2.0209
1.9575
1.8658
1.6996
1.5120
1.4020
1.3087
1.2166
1.1441
1.0774
1.0226
0.9809
0.9448
0.8526
0.6915
0.4491
0.2842
0.2582
0.2570
0.2568
0.2609
0.2632
0.2581
0.2552
0.2539
0.2527
0.2578
0.2672
0.2701
0.2655
0.2658
0.2688
0.2761
0.2767
0.2738
0.2774
0.2801
0.2817
0.2803
0.2830
0.2828
0.2876
0.2952
0.2985
0.3016
0.3092
0.3130
0.3153
0.3182
0.3304
0.3471
0.3416
0.3476
0.3497
0.3453
0.3398
0.3448
0.3563
0.3511
0.3502
0.3481
0.3519
0.3573
0.3544
0.3512
0.3489
0.3499
0.3470
0.3533
0.3409
0.3556
0.3474
0.3435
0.3460
0.3519
0.3447
0.3395
0.3488
0.3473
0.3453
0.3433
0.3484
0.3526
0.3494
0.3607
0.3694
0.4126
0.4604
0.5004
0.5163
0.5328
0.5432
0.5506
0.5485
0.5605
0.5586
0.5622
0.5727
0.5804
0.5797
0.5666
0.5700
0.5696
0.5722
0.5715
0.5656
0.5572
0.5264
0.5156
0.5473
0.6286
0.7503
0.8715
0.8825
0.7507
0.5421
0.2869
0.1091
0.0423
0.0326
0.0343
0.0256
0.0231
0.0281
0.0298
0.0229
0.0283
0.0279
0.0270
0.0300
0.0245
0.0360
0.0280
0.0270
0.0232
0.0276
0.0270
0.0237
0.0197
0.0193
0.0172
0.0140
0.0093
0.0244
0.0226
0.0192
0.0145
0.0124
0.0167
0.0182
0.0111
0.0147
0.0081
0.0151
0.0130
0.0113
0.0131
0.0067
0.0028
0.0064
0.0069
0.0082
0.0075
0.0098
-0.0008
0.0037
0.0019
0.0060
0.0057
0.0033
0.0079
0.0122
0.0091
0.0067
-0.0038
0.0033
0.0013
0.0011
0.0034
0.0051
0.0009
-0.0001
-0.0005
0.0098
-0.0003
0.0067
0.0038
0.0106
0.0000
0.0126
0.0134
0.0090
0.0116
0.0083
0.0101
0.0152
0.0010
0.0068
0.0008
0.0053
0.0090
0.0087
0.0085
0.0054
0.0089
0.0077
0.0064
0.0046
0.0058
0.0025
0.0132
0.0088
0.0043
0.0052
0.0087
0.0122
0.0023
0.0066
0.0093
0.0042
0.0042
0.0138
0.0051
-0.0055
-0.0002
0.0048
0.0063
0.0076
0.0016
-0.0005
0.0086
0.0043
-0.0016
0.0100
0.0097
0.0042
0.0092
0.0051
0.0029
0.0044
0.0033
0.0073
0.0093
0.0077
0.0093
0.0021
0.0026
0.0093
0.0068
0.0039
0.0068
0.0041
0.0053
0.0037
0.0075
0.0016
0.0000
-0.0005
0.0073
0.0076
0.0049
0.0046
0.0087
0.0106
0.0072
0.0085
0.0036
0.0044
0.0043
0.0201
0.0076
0.0075
0.0134
0.0050
0.0071
0.0032
0.0055
0.0085
0.0046
0.0023
-0.0020
0.0027
0.0060
0.0066
0.0067
0.0014
0.0166
0.0067
0.0024
0.0072
0.0062
0.0081
0.0035
0.0077
0.0101
0.0045
0.0034
0.0144
0.0078
0.0065
0.0093
0.0181
0.0028
0.0050
0.0034
0.0063
0.0150
0.0035
0.0022
0.0079
0.0034
0.0110
0.0075
0.0058
0.0085
0.0152
0.0089
0.0060
0.0017
0.0041
0.0091
0.0072
-0.0109
0.0036
0.0063
0.0080
0.0037
0.0086
0.0097
0.0088
0.0016
0.0057
0.0059
0.0139
0.0061
0.0009
0.0059
0.0126
0.0117
0.0003
0.0060
0.0075
0.0073
0.0080
0.0154
0.0136
0.0121
0.0179
0.0150
0.0125
```

Comment: wouldn't the standard way be `conv`? Also: is the shift exactly `length(f)/2` ?

Comment: It happens because your filter is causal. In other words, look at the peak of `gf`.  It is located at the `11`-th sample. So that introduces a delay of about `10` samples. To see this, imagine `gf` was `[0 0 0 1 0]`: the output would be exactly like the input but with a `3`-sample delay

Comment: @AnderBiguri I normally prefer cconv(), because thats how FT is doing. Linear convolution gives you M+N+1 length, and you need to adjust with it.

Comment: @LuisMendo Care to explain a little more? Or a link that does a good explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @NickXTsui Sorry, I was updting the comment. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @LuisMendo I know how much it is delayed (shift), but I'd like to have a theoretical explanation.

Comment: My comment was an attempt at a theoretical explanation. Try the `gf = [0 0 0 1 0]` case and you'll see why a delay is unavoidable

Comment: @LuisMendo I guess when I think the whole thing in linear convolution, I  can understand it. because the conv kernel is flipped and starts to slide through the signal, so you should have half of the kernel at beginning of the convolved signal. This is actually the source of blurry.

Comment: Instead of `x = linspace(-sz / 2, sz / 2-1, sz);`, do `x=-sz/2:sz/2`. You want to have an odd-sized filter to prevent ambiguity of where the origin is defined. You also want a symmetric filter, which it is not if you cut off the Gaussian at a different place on its two ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
f_filter = cconv(gf,f,length(f));
```

this does the trick:

```
f_filter = conv(gf,f);
f_filter = f_filter(sz/2+1:end-sz/2+1);
```

Comment: Or `conv(gf,f,'same')`, as per the documentation

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @AnderBiguri you can use the option `'same'` in your convolution fonction to preserve the original size of your array.

But if you apply a convolution with your normalized gaussian filter `gf` you will obtain a border effect.

To avoid the border effect you can apply the following tricks:

```
gf = exp(-x .^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2)); %do not normalize gf now
f_filter = conv(f,gf,'same')./conv(ones(length(f),1),gf,'same') %normalization taking into account the lenght of the convolution
```

For example I've just transformed `f` into `f = f+3`

If we do not take into account the border effect we will obtain:

[image]